# Rank of the Annihilator Matrix in Regressions?

Tags: regression, matrix

In general, for a regression $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ with an $n\times k$ matrix $X$ ($n>k$), the rank of the projection matrix $P=X\left(X^\top X\right)^{-1}X^\top$ is $k$, but is the rank (not the trace) of the annihilator matrix $M=I-P$ always $n-k$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101512/proving-the-trace-of-an-idempotent-matrix-equals-the-rank-of-the-matrix

Comment: Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985879/relation-between-trace-and-rank-for-projection-matrices

Comment: In another guise, this question asks whether the dimension of a vector space is the sum of dimensions of two orthogonal subspaces that generate it.